# How do I properly print the $node array in a views row template?

Tags: views, feeds

I'm writing a custom views-view-row-rss--content-type.tpl.php file in Drupal 6.

How do I properly print the `$node` array?

I have tried `print_r($node)` and even used `node_load()`. I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: What you mean by "properly print the $node". Do you want print it as you can use it or just for debug ?

Comment: Did you click on "theme information" within your view and "rescan template files" to make sure your new template is being used?

Comment: have you tried `print_r($row)`

Comment: For debug purposes and to see what I can pull out of the array in the context and how to address it properly. Yes, I expect I did rescan the template. I believe I did try print_r($row), but that only shows what's sent from the view if it isn't showing the node right? It has been a bit since I messed with this, but I expect to need it coming up soon.

Comment: try print_r($content);

Answer (score 0):

Install and enable the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Next, wrap the variables you wish to debug in [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/6)() or [dd](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/6)()

dpm() will output to the browser if possible.

dd() will output to a file on your server.  For example on my Ubuntu dev box it outputs by default to `/tmp/drupal-debug.txt`

Comment: Ok for Devel, but if you need a better browser display use kpr() and not dpm().